# Memory leak in a simple square detection code in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

When i run my program to detect squares, the memory becomes full in couple of seconds. I have used the same program before and never faced problem with it.

so my starting method is following in which i am ***getting the memory leak problem in the line*** `detect_squares = findSquares4( img, storage );` and if i make that a comment then there is no problem.

```
void findRect::start(Mat frame )
{
    svm svmClassObject;

    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    merging_squaresStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    namedWindow(wndname,1);

    IplImage* img = new IplImage(frame); // Mat to IplImage conversion
    cvShowImage(wndname, img);

    // find the squares
    CvSeq* detect_squares;
    detect_squares = findSquares4( img, storage );

    cvClearSeq(detect_squares);
    cvClearMemStorage( storage );
    cvClearMemStorage( merging_squaresStorage );

    delete img;
    cvWaitKey(1);

}
```

Although i have not made any changes in the method `findSquares4( img, storage );` but still i am posting it.

```
CvSeq* findRect::findSquares4( IplImage* img, CvMemStorage* storage )
{
    CvSeq* contours;
    int i, c, l, N = 11;
    CvSize sz = cvSize( img->width & -2, img->height & -2 );
    IplImage* timg = cvCloneImage( img ); // make a copy of input image
    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1 );
    IplImage* pyr = cvCreateImage( cvSize(sz.width/2, sz.height/2), 8, 3 );
    IplImage* tgray;
    CvSeq* result;
    double s, t;

    // create empty sequence that will contain points -
    // 4 points per square (the square's vertices)
    CvSeq* squares = cvCreateSeq( 0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), storage );

    cvSetImageROI( timg, cvRect( 0, 0, sz.width, sz.height ));

    cvPyrDown( timg, pyr, 7 );
    cvPyrUp( pyr, timg, 7 );
    tgray = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1 );

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        // extract the c-th color plane
        cvSetImageCOI( timg, c+1 );
        cvCopy( timg, tgray, 0 );

        // try several threshold levels
        for( l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {

            if( l == 0 )
            {

                cvCanny( tgray, gray, 0, thresh, 5 );
                cvDilate( gray, gray, 0, 1 );
            }
            else
            {

                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                cvThreshold( tgray, gray, (l+1)*255/N, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
            }

            cvFindContours( gray, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0) );

            // test each contour
            while( contours )
            {

                result = cvApproxPoly( contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0 );

                if( result->total == 4   &&    fabs(cvContourArea(result,CV_WHOLE_SEQ)) > 1000  &&  cvCheckContourConvexity(result) )
                {
                    s = 0;

                    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
                    {

                        if( i >= 2 )
                        {
                            t = fabs(angle(
                                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i ),
                                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i-2 ),
                                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i-1 ))
                                        );
                            s = s > t ? s : t;
                        }
                    }


                    if(  ( s < 0.5 ) )//  && dx1< (height_image/3)
                    {
                        CvPoint *pt[4];
                        CvPoint *final_square_pt[4];
                        for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                        {
                            //cvSeqPush( squares,(CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i ));
                            pt[i]= (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
                        }
                         flag++;   // It can represent the maiximum number of selected squares---without eliminating bigger ones

                        int difference_x= std::abs(pt[1]->x  -  pt[0]->x);
                        int difference_y= std::abs(pt[3]->y  -  pt[0]->y);
                        int difference_x1to3= std::abs(pt[3]->x  -  pt[1]->x);

                        if( difference_x>10 && difference_x<150 && difference_y>10 && difference_y<150 && difference_x1to3>10 && difference_x1to3<300 )//(height_image/5)  )
                        {
                            for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                            {
                                cvSeqPush( squares,(CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i ));
                                final_square_pt[i]= (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i); // final_square_pt[i] consists of 4 points which makes a Single Square
                            }
                            actual_flag++;
                        }
                    }

                }

                // take the next contour
                contours = contours->h_next;
            }
        }
    }

    // release all the temporary images
    cvReleaseImage( &gray );
    cvReleaseImage( &pyr );
    cvReleaseImage( &tgray );
    cvReleaseImage( &timg );

    return squares;
}
```

Comment: Why are you sure that it's memory leak instead of just high peak memory requirement?

Comment: because after sometime, my laptop gets hang completly. I have ran this application several times before and never faced this kind of problem. Secondly, as i have mentioned, if i make that line comment then it run smoothly

Comment: function findSquares4() returns a pointer, should this pointer be freed?

Comment: @Matt It seems that the pointer returned by `findSquares4()` is allocated from `storage`, which is freed by `cvClearMemStorage()`.

Comment: @Matt: i have tried using `cvClearSeq(detect_squares);` but no benefit.

Comment: why you use outdated C API? IplImages *, cvCreateImage ... 
C++ API will manage deleting memory automatically, so convert to updated opencv vesrion

Comment: @dervish: yeah its old version but actually its a part of an another application so just wanted to use it in that way only

Comment: is `contours` freed somewhere? It's some time ago that I used the C API, so I'm not sure... I guess that's part of the storage, too? But is it freed during runtime?

Comment: `contours` are also using the memory blocks provided my `storage` and `storage` has been freed in the calling methods.